# Percentage/proportion of published papers with DSGE models

Tags: macroeconomics, dsge

I remember reading a few years back an article that showed an interesting graphic with the percentage/proportion of published papers with DSGE models across time. I've tried searching, but I get so many results related to DSGE, but not to what I'm looking for...

I'm looking for a reference with that graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have been thinking of a chart originally from *The Economist* Nov 24th 2016 article "[Economists are prone to fads, and the latest is machine learning](https://www.economist.com/finance-and-economics/2016/11/24/economists-are-prone-to-fads-and-the-latest-is-machine-learning)" though I cannot see it there.  There is [a copy of the chart](https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-MX9aQjPRfIg/WgyD4CYTMHI/AAAAAAAAKaE/NNdEgGBXstAVfbJYRCRLLZdlwngaVIWaQCLcBGAs/s1600/dsge.png) visible at [Noah Smith's blog](http://noahpinionblog.blogspot.com/2017/11/the-cackling-cartoon-villain-defense-of.html)

It shows an analysis by *The Economist* of the key words in working-paper abstracts published by the National Bureau of Economic Research, with lines for laboratory experiments, randomised control trials (RCTs), difference-in-differences, regression discontinuity, machine learning or big data, and DSGE

Comment: Henry, I think you're right! Thanks! 
By the way, do you know how to have access to that data?

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. - Sorry - I have nothing beyond those links